# Eclipse cannot find JVM

Tags: java, eclipse

So eclipse cannot find the JVM.

- I have tried to change the eclipse.ini to include the jvm.dll and the javaw.exe where I am absolutely sure it included the right path.
- I have tried to change the environment variables to include the java.exe and the javaw.exe path but neither worked.
- I have also tried to reinstall eclipse and furthermore I have ensured I have a 64-bit installation of eclipse (and of course my computer is 64-bit) and the jre and the jdk are both 64-bit.

What am I to do?

**EDIT:**

Path environment variable

```
C:\WinAVR-20100110\bin;C:\WinAVR-20100110\utils\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\java.exe;C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe
```

Eclipse.ini

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar

--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20140116-2212

 -product

org.eclipse.epp.package.standard.product

--launcher.defaultAction
openFile

--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M

-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m

--launcher.defaultAction
openFile

--launcher.appendVmargs

-vmargs

-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6

-Xms40m

-Xmx512m


-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe
```

Comment: Eclipse standard 4.3.2

Comment: Show us your eclipse.ini file and your PATH variable. I assume from your mention of DLLs that you are on windows?

Comment: Yes I am running windows 8.1

Comment: Oh man, this is going to be painful to solve via SO lol.

Comment: Note that your `-vm` parameter should be listed before your `-vmargs`: http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini

Comment: Does Eclipse show you an error message when it tries to start? If so, please add that to your question too.

Comment: Also, your path variable must contain the path only until bin directory. It must not include the file name 'java.exe'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `-vm` argument should be listed before your `-vmargs` arguments:

```
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin

-vmargs

-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6

-Xms40m

-Xmx512m
```

See http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#Specifying_the_JVM.